# You are using App ID default configuration Warning after configuring Identify Providers IBM Bluemix APPID

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

Followed the instructions in https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/identity-providers.html#setting-up-idp to setup the Identity providers. 
Even after configuring the Identity providers seeing the You are using App ID default configuration warning.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqaKN.png)

Comment: From the image you gave I see yo enabled facebook, but did you actually edit (press the edit button) and changed (and saved) the data?
Can you show that screen too?

Answer (score 0):

It was a defect in the service dashboard that have already been fixed.
Please let us know if you're still experiencing this problem.

Thanks,
Vitaly